# jQuery function not working inside a modal

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am using Foundation reveal [modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKL5O.png) with id="sizesModal" that contains user inputs which are supposed to be previewed under Sizes & Qty Preview when submitted with "save" button

There is a function inside footer that is called updateSizes

```
 function updateSizes() {
 var sizeString = '';
 for (var i=1;i<=12;i++){
  if(jQuery('#size'+i).val() != ''){
    sizeString +=  jQuery('#size'+i).val()+':'+jQuery('#qty'+i).val()+',';
      }
  }
  jQuery('#sizes').val(sizeString);
}
```

inside my reveal modal div on products.php , there is a button for submitting

```
 </button>
 <button class="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sizesModal" click="updateSizes();jQuery('#sizesModal').modal('toggle');return false;"> Save Changes
 </button>
```

I am not getting any console messages, but the button is not outputting anything into 
[Sizes & Qty Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WywlA.png)

I have included all the scripts from foundation and the footer page

Comment: about attributes `click` is not an attribute `onclick` is a right one

Comment: Somebody told me exactly the opposite thing. with onclick I get an console : TypeError: jQuery(...).modal is not a function

Comment: first use the right code then look to fix the errors .. but with `click` you'll not receive anything .. so you need to use `onclick` then see why `jQuery(...).modal is not a function`

Comment: And while you got `jQuery(...).modal is not a function` we need to see how you include your js files

Comment: I know I don't have  typo, and than it must be something with foundation. But I was looking into it and can't find the solution

Comment: ok use `onclick` and remove `jQuery('#sizesModal').modal('toggle');return false;` from it .. just leave the function and see what you'll get

Comment: With only onclick="updateSizes();" it gives me no console logs

Comment: ok @Lortnok I'll up vote your question maybe someone else can help .. Good Luck :)

Comment: There is no console statement in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by applying id to button "saveChangesSizes"  and than doing script this way inside products page

```
$("#saveChangesSizes").click(function(){
console.log("1");
var velicine="";
var niz=new Array();
for(var i=1; i<=12;i++){
    if($("#size_" + i).val()!=""){
        niz.push({size: $("#size_" + i).val(), qty: $("#qty_" + i).val()});
        velicine+=$("#size_" + i).val() + ":" + $("#qty_" + i).val() + ",";
    }
}
console.log(niz);
if(velicine.length>0){
    velicine=velicine.substring(0,velicine.length-1);
}
$("#qtyandsizes").val(JSON.stringify(niz));

$("#size").val(velicine);
 $("#sizesModal").foundation("close");
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check does the if statement Is executed. I think there might be possibility that .Val() return something else.